# Blender Documentation

Tags: versions

I am a beginner in Blender 3D, but I can already appreciate the power of this app.

I downloaded this book --> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/BlenderDocumentation.pdf

However, I am encountering a lot of problems because my version 2.72b and most of what I am reading refers to UI which dates back to older versions.

Can someone help me identify a beginners book (in pdf format) that is updated for the version 2.70+.

Comment: I don't think there's one; at least an official one

Comment: 2.70+ is still very new, so most of the stuff is in online tutorials, not books/pdfs.

Comment: Blenders UI has changed with version 2.5 you should ignore older tutorials, for the first steps check http://gryllus.net/Blender/PDFTutorials/AllPDFTutorials.html this question should be closed since we decided to have only one resource question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender recommendations for further resources are always welcome.